# Speeding up PHPUnit startup when code coverage is not required

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage, codeception

I am using PHPUnit in my Codeception unit tests. I am not interested in code coverage yet, so I would like to completely disable it, especially because it delays my tests by 8..12 seconds. This becomes annoying when tests are configured to be run automatically when files change.

I debugged PHPUnit code to see why it is starting up so long and found out that it spends up to 12 seconds inside `getCodeCoverageFilter` looping through `getBlacklistedDirectories` and collecting filenames calling `addDirectoryToBlacklist`.

**Is there any way to disable processing `getCodeCoverageFilter`in Codeception or PHPUnit itself without directly hacking its code?**

Here is my current phpunit.xml at the root of my Laravel 5 project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <directory>./vendor/</directory>
            <directory>./database/</directory>
            <directory>./public/</directory>     
            <directory>./resources/</directory>
            <directory>./storage/</directory>
            <directory>./tests/</directory>
        </blacklist>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">app/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the line

```
<log type="coverage-html" target="coverage"/>
```

from your `phpunit.xml`

In fact, I use two xml files.

One standard `phpunit.xml` that is used on a remote code inspection service, and one that I specifically named `phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml` without code coverage, that I use locally while developing.

You can specify which xml file to use via phpunit's `c` flag, e.g:

```
./phpunit -c tests/phpunit_no_code_coverage.xml --testsuite suite_name
```

The result is rather huge, my testsuite runs now rather fast, on average taking ~15 seconds, whereas it before took 110 seconds.

Comment: I don't have that line. Still, getCodeCoverageFilter is being called. I'll update my question with my current phpunit.xml.

Answer (score 0):

According to [codeception documentation](http://codeception.com/docs/11-Codecoverage), the code coverage is enabled in `codeception.yml`. Try:

```
coverage:
    enabled: false
```

Or removing the key.

Comment: Still does not help - I don't have that key and I tried setting it to false, but still `getCodeCoverageFilter` gets executed.